# how to get other user media from instagram node.js

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get media photos of another user but it return me an empty array. I am using instagram-node library in node.js. Below is the code

```
instagram.use({access_token: 'asdasdasd.adad.gggggggggggggggg'});

instagram.user_search('arsenal', function (err, result, remaining, limit) {
            console.log(result)

            instagram.user_media_recent(result[0].id, function (err, result2, remaining, limit) {
                console.log(result2)
            });

        });
```

console.log(result) return me with empty array []. How can I get the media of another user using instagram-node or anoy other suggested library or should I use native instagram library to be used to fetch data?

Comment: Are u in sandbox mode ?

Comment: @krisrak yes in sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox mode, you will only see your and your sandbox users in API response, once u go live, you will see all users if you have `public_content` scope permission

read more about sandbox mode here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/